# Can anyone tell me why this Jquery isn't working?

Tags: jquery

I have written a jQuery function that is for a treeview that has 5 levels that you can click into to see the next level of data my last level that I was working on does not seem to be working at all. It seems to me that the jQuery is not even being called because usually it would at least open the tree with no data in it for a second if it was my controller.  Below I have posted my jQuery for the level I am working on right now and all the levels above it for analysis. Any advice or help would be very much appreciated! Please let me know if you need the controllers as well.

**Bottom Level jQuery This is the part not working(Does not even click)**

```
//Spend Category function for monthly
        pa_click = function (pa_label) {
            PA_ID = pa_label.getAttribute('pa_id');

        var pa_details = document.getElementById('pa-details-' + PA_ID);
        alert('message');
        jQuery.getJSON('@Url.Action("getAjaxSCs")', { PA: pa_label.title }, function (SCS) {
            pa_details.innerHTML = "";
            jQuery.each(SCS, function (index, SC) {
                months_html = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                    months_html +=
                                        '<div id="SC-' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '-' + months[i] + '" class="month-wrapper tree border-white">' +
                                        months[i] +
                                        '</div>';
                }

                pa_details.innerHTML +=
                alert('message');
                        '<div id ="Spend-Category-' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '" class="sc-wrapper tree border">' +
                            '<div id ="sc-title-' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '" class="sc-title">' +
                                '<div class = "sc-label" title = "' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '" SC_id="' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '" onclick = "sc_click(this)">' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '</div>' +
                                months_html +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div id="sc-details-' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '" class = "pa-details" style = "display:none">' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '</div>' +
                        '</div>';
            })
        });
        jQuery('#pa-details-' + PA_ID).show('slide', { direction: 'up' }, 'fast');

    };
```

**The jQuery in its entirety**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var IA_ID = 0;
        var months = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

        // Major Program function for monthly
        $(".ia-label").click(function () {

            IA_ID = this.getAttribute('investment_area_id');
            var ia_details = document.getElementById('ia-details-' + IA_ID);

            jQuery.getJSON('@Url.Action("getAjaxMPs")', { IA: this.title }, function (MPS) {
                ia_details.innerHTML = "";
                jQuery.each(MPS, function (index, MP) {
                    months_html = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                        months_html +=
                                            '<div id="MP-' + MP.MP_ID + '-' + months[i] + '" class="month-wrapper tree border-white">' +
                                            months[i] +
                                            '</div>';
                    }

                    ia_details.innerHTML +=
                            '<div id="MP-' + MP.MP_ID + '" class="mp-wrapper tree border">' +
                                '<div id="mp-title-' + MP.MP_ID + '" class="mp-title">' +
                                    '<div class="mp-label" title="' + MP.MP_NAME + '" major_program_id="' + MP.MP_ID + '" onclick="mp_click(this)">' + MP.MP_NAME + '</div>' +
                                    months_html +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div id="mp-details-' + MP.MP_ID + '" class="mp-details" style="display:none">' + MP.MP_NAME + '</div>' +
                            '</div>';

                })
            });
            jQuery('#ia-details-' + IA_ID).show('slide', { direction: 'up' }, 'fast');





        });
        //Sub Program function for monthly
        mp_click = function (mp_label) {
            MP_ID = mp_label.getAttribute('major_program_id');
            var mp_details = document.getElementById('mp-details-' + MP_ID);

            jQuery.getJSON('@Url.Action("getAjaxSPs")', { MP: mp_label.title }, function (SPS) {
                mp_details.innerHTML = "";
                jQuery.each(SPS, function (index, SP) {
                    months_html = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                        months_html +=
                                            '<div id="SP-' + SP.SP_ID + '-' + months[i] + '" class="month-wrapper tree border-white">' +
                                            months[i] +
                                            '</div>';
                    }

                    mp_details.innerHTML +=
                            '<div id ="Sub-Program-' + SP.SP_ID + '" class="sp-wrapper tree border">' +
                                '<div id ="sp-title-' + SP.SP_ID + '" class="sp-title">' +
                                    '<div class = "sp-label" title = "' + SP.SP_NAME + '" sub_program_id="' + SP.SP_ID + '" onclick="sp_click(this)">' + SP.SP_NAME + '</div>' +
                                    months_html +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div id="sp-details-' + SP.SP_ID + '" class = "mp-details" style = "display:none">' + SP.SP_NAME + '</div>' +
                            '</div>';
                })
            });
            jQuery('#mp-details-' + MP_ID).show('slide', { direction: 'up' }, 'fast');

        };

        //PA function for monthly
        sp_click = function (sp_label) {
            SP_ID = sp_label.getAttribute('sub_program_id');
            var sp_details = document.getElementById('sp-details-' + SP_ID);

            jQuery.getJSON('@Url.Action("getAjaxPAs")', { SP: sp_label.title }, function (PAS) {
                sp_details.innerHTML = "";
                jQuery.each(PAS, function (index, PA) {
                    months_html = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                        months_html +=
                                            '<div id="PA-' + PA.PA + '-' + months[i] + '" class="month-wrapper tree border-white">' +
                                            months[i] +
                                            '</div>';
                    }

                    sp_details.innerHTML +=

                            '<div id ="PA-' + PA.PA + '" class="sp-wrapper tree border">' +
                                '<div id ="pa-title-' + PA.PA + '" class="pa-title">' +
                                    '<div class = "pa-label" title = "' + PA.PA + '" PA_id="' + PA.PA + '" onlclick = "pa_click(this)">' + PA.PA + '</div>' +
                                    months_html +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div id="pa-details-' + PA.PA + '" class = "sp-details" style = "display:none">' + PA.PA + '</div>' +
                            '</div>';
                })
            });
            jQuery('#sp-details-' + SP_ID).show('slide', { direction: 'up' }, 'fast');

        };

        //Spend Category function for monthly
        pa_click = function (pa_label) {
            PA_ID = pa_label.getAttribute('pa_id');

            var pa_details = document.getElementById('pa-details-' + PA_ID);
            alert('message');
            jQuery.getJSON('@Url.Action("getAjaxSCs")', { PA: pa_label.title }, function (SCS) {
                pa_details.innerHTML = "";
                jQuery.each(SCS, function (index, SC) {
                    months_html = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                        months_html +=
                                            '<div id="SC-' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '-' + months[i] + '" class="month-wrapper tree border-white">' +
                                            months[i] +
                                            '</div>';
                    }

                    pa_details.innerHTML +=
                    alert('message');
                            '<div id ="Spend-Category-' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '" class="sc-wrapper tree border">' +
                                '<div id ="sc-title-' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '" class="sc-title">' +
                                    '<div class = "sc-label" title = "' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '" SC_id="' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '" onclick = "sc_click(this)">' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '</div>' +
                                    months_html +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div id="sc-details-' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '" class = "pa-details" style = "display:none">' + SC.SPEND_CATEGORY + '</div>' +
                            '</div>';
                })
            });
            jQuery('#pa-details-' + PA_ID).show('slide', { direction: 'up' }, 'fast');

        };





    });
</script>
```

Comment: do you include jQuery library?

Comment: your console will be your best friend then

Comment: Note that your functions are defined as variables within the `DOMReady` listener, and not globally. Since you're not using `var` to introduce them, this will make them global variables in most browsers, but older IE versions won't allow this. To the extent that this code works, it does so only incidentally.

Comment: Other side notes: since you're receiving `$` as a paramter to `DOMReady`, it's safe to use that instead of `jQuery` within that scope, even if you do have conflicting libraries, such as Prototype. DOM modification through manually hacked HTML strings quickly becomes error prone, with escapes and whatnot. Consider building the DOM nodes through library functions instead `$('<div/>', { id = 'PA-' + PA.PA, 'class': 'sp-wrapper tree border' }).appendTo(sp_details)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'<div class = "pa-label" title = "' + PA.PA + '" PA_id="' + PA.PA + '" onlclick = "pa_click(this)">' + PA.PA`

You mispelled `onclick`, that should fix it!

On a side note: It is easier & better performance-wise to create a live DOM eventhandler for this type of situation. Adding so many onclick events (especially in IE, creates an insane amount of script events (that in the end are all the same) on each one of these items)!

Just do:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pa-label', function (e) { 
    pa_click(this);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I have been staring at the code for hours now, how one little mistake can mess everything up! You Rock!